# Why do Star Trek characters pronounce sensor sen-SOR?

Tags: star-trek

Why do most characters in Star Trek pronounce sensors as senSORs with a heavy emphasis on the second syllable?

In most American accents you would say "sensers" with more of an emphasis on the first syllable. I imagine most in British accents one would say "sensuzz".

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of emphasis so much as of vowel. The emphasis is still on the first syllable; it's just that the second syllable is a genuine O sound instead of a schwa.

Comment: (Also, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/26dnda/something_small_i_noticed_while_watching_tng/) reddit thread seems to suggest that it's a combination of Leonard Nimoy overcompensating for his Boston accent and maybe Patrick Stewart being theatrical, but with no real backing...)

Comment: In-universe, this could simply be attributed to the development of the english language, see this article... https://www.vocabulary.com/lists/432678#view=notes

Comment: This seems like a local thing, because I personally would pronounce it with the "or" ending. Maybe not a *heavy emphasis* on the second syllable, but definitely there. To-mā-to/To-mă-to?

Comment: Most Scots would pronounce it with equal stress on the two syllables.

Comment: @user23614 No, they wouldn't. They may pronounce it with a full, unreduced vowel in the second syllable, and they may even assign secondary stress to the second syllable; but it is not possible to have two consecutive primary stresses within a single, non-compound word in English (or the vast majority of the world’s other languages, for that matter). Consider the (somewhat far-fetched, but can't think of a better example) difference between money that is _counterfeit_ [primary + unstressed + secondary] vs. an annoying customer in a shop having a _counter fit_ [primary + unstressed + primary].

Comment: I am a Scot and I do pronounce it with neither syllable stressed

Comment: @user23614 With _neither_ syllable stressed? Even when saying the word in isolation? That is also not possible in English; only a very small subset of function words are allowed to remain unstressed when spoken in isolation (_a, the_, basically); all others must have at least one stressed syllable.

Comment: I believe that in Mr Nimoy's autobiography, he mentioned that Gene Roddenberry figured Spock learned English from the library tapes, which just happened to use BBC/British pronunciation. That idea went by the wayside later, but you hear Spock giving unusual stress on certain syllables in words

Answer (score 3):

Given that Nimoy was the first in the franchise to do it, and that it's an unusual pronunciation, it's safe to say that everyone else does so in his memory. So why did he do it?

Maybe it was (compensating for) his Boston accent, as some faceless netizens have speculated:

> [He's from Boston, and that's one thick accent they have. Might be residual and subconscious on his part.](https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/2bw6h1/spocknimoys_pronunciation_of_a/cj9mwyu)

> [I thought Nimoy said sensors that way because his Boston accent was too resilient and he couldn't not say "sensahs"?](https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/26dnda/something_small_i_noticed_while_watching_tng/chql2ep)

In-universe, Spock is an alien and a very methodical speaker (traits that are also easily recognized in the other main culprits, Worf and Tuvok). The [script](http://www.knowitalljoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Star-Trek-the-Cage-Roddenberry-Copy.pdf) for *[The Cage](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cage_(episode))* says when he's introduced:

> He speaks with the almost British accent of one who has learned the language in textbooks.

Indeed, in *[The Big Book of Beastly Mispronunciations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0395893380)* ([pp. 220-221](https://books.google.com/books?id=7iocw3kK9BIC&pg=PA220#v=onepage&q&f=false)), [Charles Harrington Elster](http://members.authorsguild.net/chelster/bio.htm) says that "SEN-sor" is an example of [overpronunciation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overpronounce), which is a tendency of Spock's that has filtered into American speaking habits as what Elster calls "sci-fi pronunciation" or "Hollywood Hyperspeak."